# how to save foreign key from django html template

Tags: python, django

I want to save data from html template select field in django.

html example code:

```
<label for="type" style="color:red;">Short Name *</label>

<input type="text" name="short_name" class="form-control" required placeholder="">
                                    <br> <br>
<select style='bakground-color:red' name="category" required class="form-control show-tick">
        <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
        {% for cat in category %}
            <option value="{{ cat }}">{{ cat }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Django code:

```
Views.py
```

```
    def addBooks(request):
        template = 'admin_panel/add_books.html'
        category = Category.objects.all()
        
     
        
        book_details = BookDetails.objects.all()
        
        context = {
            "page_title": "Add Book",
            "category": category,
            
            "book_details" :book_details,
            
            }

      if request.method == "POST":
        short_name = request.POST.get('short_name', None) 
        category = request.POST.get('category',None)
       
        book_details = BookDetails.objects.create(short_name=short_name, category=category)

      return render(request, template,context)
```

models.py

```
class BookDetails(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    short_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, db_index=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
```

Error Showing:
ValueError at /superadmin/add_books/
Cannot assign "'Story'": "BookDetails.category" must be a "Category" instance.

[image]

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In tamplate
`option value={{cat.id}}`

In view:

```
BookDetails.objects.create(short_name=short_name, category_id=category)
```